# Casting HashMap of subtypes to HashMap of supertypes

Tags: java, generics, casting, hashmap

I do have troubles manipulating hashmaps. My problem is quite simple, but I cannot make it work...

I have an interface named `MultilineWritable`. My classes that do need to be marshalled on flat files do implement this interface, which define a `String toFlatFormat()` function and its opposite `init(String flatFormat)`.

Now imagine that the `Contract` class do implement `MultilineWritable` and is identified by integers while the `Person` class do also implement this interface but is identified by Strings.

My function to marshall the HashMaps of contracts and persons looks like :

```
public void marshall(HashMap<Object, MultilineWritable>){}
```

My problem is I cannot find a way to cast a `HashMap<String, Person>` to a `HashMap<Object, MultilineWritable>`, even if `String` extends `Object` and `Person` extends `MultilineWritable`. Same for the casting of a `HashMap<Integer, Contract>`... consequently I cannot call my generic function.

Thx for any help regarding this problem.

Comment: try this public void marshall(HashMap<? extends Object, ? extnds MultilineWritable>){}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your `marshall` method only ever *reads* values, you should just change the declaration to:

```
public void marshall(HashMap<?, ? extends MultilineWritable> map)
```

The problem is that if the existing method call were allowed, it could try to put *any* `MultilineWritable` into the map - even if it was the wrong map type:

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<String, Person>();

// What would you want map.put("foo", new Contact()) to do inside marshall?
marshall(map);
```

EDIT: For more details about wildcards, see the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What%20is%20a%20wildcard%20instantiation?).

Comment: It just uses the two functions defined by my interface and uses a `String.valueOf()` on the key. Nothing more. Working fine. That was so simple. I'm not used to this ? notation, could you explain why it is different to write `? extends MultilineWritable` compared to just `MultilineWritable` ?

Comment: I dont fully understand the reason of this notation. Why is there a need of the wildcards ? If my `List<Apple>` becomes a `List<Fruit>` for the time of a function, why not allow it by a cast ? As long as it uses only the functions of the `Fruit` class, I dont see the harm. And if it tries once to convert a `Banana` to an `Apple`, a runtime `ClassCastException` would raise just as expected... I understand how it works, I'm now trying to understand why it was necessary for the Java language.

Comment: @Wis: Because a `List<Apple>` *isn't* a `List<Fruit>`. You can add a `Banana` to a `List<Fruit>`, but you can't add a `Banana` to a `List<Apple>`. The idea of generics is to make things safe at *compile-time*, rather than at *execution-time*. Additionally, due to type erasure, the list itself doesn't really *have* an element type, so you wouldn't be able to get that `ClassCastException` either.

Comment: @Jon: You would be able to get the ClassCastException but not at insert time, only when doing e.g. `Apple apple = list.get(0);` when the element at position 0 is actually a Banana.  But of course, you want it at insert time (well, actually you just don't want it to compile).

Comment: I'm getting it. What is quite strange is the fact I do need a notation associated to Generics without using anything of generics. In my case, I'm using the notation just to bypass the "type-safe-check" at compile time. But Generics can be much more than that.

Comment: @Wis: But you *are* using generics. You're not *bypassing* the type-safe-check... your going along with it. I don't see anything strange about this...

Comment: I think I'm just uneasy with the notation. But works perfectly, that's the main point.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to pass a `specific type` into a `generic type`. You need to use java's `generics` feature. Generics offer `compile time safety only`, so while you are allowed to pass specific types into a function that takes genetic type, you are not allowed to modify the collection or the map.

So in short your anser is:

```
public void marshall(HashMap<? extends Object, ? extends MultilineWritable> map)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java Generics are [not Covariant](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/Unsoundness/). So you cannot do following

```
    List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Number> numList = new ArrayList<Number>();
    numList = numList; //Error
    numList = (List<Number>)intList; //error
```

Generics are used by the compiler to typsafety. The actual type information (of the collections i.e. this is List of Integers) etc is lost at runtime.